# all nested descendants Deep nesting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have Taxons table with all parent child records:

```
<ActiveRecord::Relation [

#<Spree::Taxon id: 1, parent_id: nil, position: 0, name: "Brands", 
permalink: "brands", taxonomy_id: 1, lft: 1, rgt: 20, 
icon_file_name: nil, icon_content_type: nil, icon_file_size: nil, icon_updated_at: nil, 
description: nil, created_at: "2017-06-14 08:52:19", updated_at: "2017-06-23 06:34:11", 
meta_title: nil, meta_description: nil, meta_keywords: nil, depth: 0>, 

#<Spree::Taxon id: 2, parent_id: nil, position: 0, name: "Brand", permalink: "brand", taxonomy_id: 2, lft: 21, rgt: 22, 
icon_file_name: nil, icon_content_type: nil, icon_file_size: nil, icon_updated_at: nil, description: nil, 
created_at: "2017-06-14 08:52:19", updated_at: "2017- 06-14 08:52:22", meta_title: nil, 
meta_description: nil, meta_keywords: nil, depth: 0>, 

#<Spree::Taxon id: 3, parent_id: 1, position: 0, name: 
"Bags", permalink: "brands/bags", taxonomy_id: 1, lft: 2, rgt: 3, 
icon_file_name: nil, icon_content_type: nil, icon_file_size: nil, 
icon_updated_at: nil, description: nil, created_at: "2017-06-14 
08:52:19", updated_at: "2017-06-21 05:03:52", meta_title: nil, 
meta_description: nil, meta_keywords: nil, depth: 0>, 

#<Spree::Taxon id: 4, parent_id: 1, position: 0, name: "Mugs", permalink: 
"brands/mugs", taxonomy_id: 1, lft: 4, rgt: 5, icon_file_name: nil, 
icon_content_type: nil, icon_file_size: nil, icon_updated_at: nil, 
description: nil, created_at: "2017-06-14 08:52:20", updated_at: "2017-
06-14 08:58:29", meta_title: nil, meta_description: nil, meta_keywords: 
nil, depth: 0>, 

#<Spree::Taxon id: 5, parent_id: 1, position: 0, name: 
"Clothing", permalink: "brands/clothing", taxonomy_id: 1, lft: 6, rgt: 
11, icon_file_name: nil, icon_content_type: nil, icon_file_size: nil, 
icon_updated_at: nil, description: nil, created_at: "2017-06-14 
08:52:20", updated_at: "2017-06-23 06:34:11", meta_title: nil, 
meta_description: nil, meta_keywords: nil, depth: 0>, 

#<Spree::Taxon id: 6, parent_id: 5, position: 0, name: "Shirts", permalink: 
"brands/clothing/shirts", taxonomy_id: 1, lft: 7, rgt: 8, 
icon_file_name: nil, icon_content_type: nil, icon_file_size: nil, 
icon_updated_at: nil, description: nil, created_at: "2017-06-14 
08:52:20", updated_at: "2017-06-20 06:10:16", meta_title: nil, 
meta_description: nil, meta_keywords: nil, depth: 0>, 

#<Spree::Taxon id: 7, parent_id: 5, position: 0, name: "T-Shirts", permalink: 
"brands/clothing/t-shirts", taxonomy_id: 1, lft: 9, rgt: 10, 
icon_file_name: nil, icon_content_type: nil, icon_file_size: nil, 
icon_updated_at: nil, description: nil, created_at: "2017-06-14 
08:52:20", updated_at: "2017-06-23 06:34:11", meta_title: nil, 
meta_description: nil, meta_keywords: nil, depth: 0>, 

#<Spree::Taxon id: 8, parent_id: 1, position: 0, name: "Ruby", permalink: 
"brands/ruby", taxonomy_id: 2, lft: 12, rgt: 13, icon_file_name: nil, 
icon_content_type: nil, icon_file_size: nil, icon_updated_at: nil, 
description: nil, created_at: "2017-06-14 08:52:21", updated_at: "2017-
06-20 06:09:31", meta_title: nil, meta_description: nil, meta_keywords: 
nil, depth: 0>, 

#<Spree::Taxon id: 9, parent_id: 1, position: 0, name: 
"Apache", permalink: "brands/apache", taxonomy_id: 2, lft: 14, rgt: 15, 
icon_file_name: nil, icon_content_type: nil, icon_file_size: nil, 
icon_updated_at: nil, description: nil, created_at: "2017-06-14 
08:52:21", updated_at: "2017-06-23 06:34:11", meta_title: nil, 
meta_description: nil, meta_keywords: nil, depth: 0>, 

#<Spree::Taxon id: 10, parent_id: 1, position: 0, name: "Spree", permalink: 
"brands/spree", taxonomy_id: 2, lft: 16, rgt: 17, icon_file_name: nil, 
icon_content_type: nil, icon_file_size: nil, icon_updated_at: nil, 
description: nil, created_at: "2017-06-14 08:52:21", updated_at: "2017-
06-14 08:58:29", meta_title: nil, meta_description: nil, meta_keywords: 
nil, depth: 0>, ...]>
```

I need a tree structure like this:

```
parent1(first taxon(first record) with all child if it has)
  - child1
  - child2
  - child3
    - child7
    - child9
  - child4
  - child5
parent2(it has no child)
parent3(Not it has child)
  - child7
  - child9
```

I short I need each individual taxon with its nested child.

I have tried something like:

```
Taxon.all.each do |i| 
     i.self_and_descendants.each do |j|
       taxon_with_childs << j
     end
```

But this gives plain array, but I want array with parent child nesting.

I have also tried:

```
Taxon.each_with_level(Taxon.root.self_and_descendants) do |taxon, level|
    taxon_with_childs << taxon
  end
```

But this is giving only first record's children and not a deep nesting.

Comment: no i am not using...

Comment: @spickermann do you have any idea  how to solve this

Comment: `Spree::Taxon` uses `acts_as_nested_set` internally (see: the [code on GitHub](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/taxon.rb#L10)). Can you add an example of the expected output? Do we need a nested array or a flat array?

Comment: @spickermann I need nested array for each element ,if exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it can be done by DFS function

```
def add_self_and_descendents(x, taxon_with_childs)
  taxon_with_childs << x
  x.descendants.each do |y|
    add_self_and_descendents(y, taxon_with_childs)
  end
end

Taxon.all.each do |i| 
  add_self_and_descendents(i, taxon_with_childs)
end
```

And it will have long time if the database is bigger and bigger.
But there's no other way to do it with short time because database operation functions only use constant values such as *Taxon.where(:parent_id => 1 )*

Hope this works for you.